# How to avoid duplicate entries of a record when Exporting SQL server data to an Excel in C#?

Tags: c#

I have requirement to export SQL Script data to an excel using C#.Net.
Currently I face issue in avoiding duplicat values for columns, when a record has multiple values for a column it should look like as in the bellow, the entire record should not repeated for each values of the column.

should I handle it in application level or in Sql script. please advice me.

Currently I get data set and bind it to a grid view and then do the export to excel function.

[image: Excel format]

for example Sql Data could be

```
   select B.BID, B.BName, M.Year
   from tbl_B B
   inner join tbl_Master M ON B.BID = fm.BIDFK
   where B.BName = 'B9'
   Group By B.BID, B.BName, M.Year
```

And the Result

[image]

Comment: Do I need to go with nested grid view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have cleared out this issue on C# side, I use nested grid-view to bind multiple valued columns for a record, when exporting to excel clear controls inside the parent grid-view to export data from all grid-view.

Answer (score 0):

I think it need to be done in SQL script.
It's not complicated logic to apply .

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit on how the SQL Query can be constructed?

Comment: I think the column should be splited by some delimeter. It's obvious need to be done in store procedure. SP's are compiled and run faster

Comment: Yes I do SP. you meant to say that a record should be in a single row and multiple valued columns as string of values spited by delimiter, if so how do we export the data to excel as in the figure?

Comment: Please add to the question data that you need to export

Answer (score 0):

I would seriously look at using the Report Viewer control and a local report rather than trying to build the Excel sheet by hand.  Check out [GotReportViewer.com](http://gotreportviewer.com/) and the examples on the right cover exporting to Excel, and using the control from a console application.